# Serving large json arrays with python(django)

Tags: python, json, django

I want  to create a web application using django that reads a large amount of data from a database (large querysets), and create json responses with the data.

How can I do that efficiently? It is likely that the results will contain thousands or millions of rows.

I am using django because of its authentication. Is there a better way?

This application will only be serving json responses and no web pages (or admin inferace) will be shown.

update (pseudo code):

```
@login_required
def GetAllNews(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json', models.News.objects.all() , fields=('title', 'desc'))
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: What db backend are you using nosql or sql?

Comment: becuase the some data models are related probably postgresql will be used and with less possibility cassandra.

Comment: What's "large amount of data" in MB?

Comment: Can you post some pseudocode? Like, step 1: do this. step 2: do that. etc.

Comment: because data are only text based i do not think the size of data will be very much and because of using gzip size of data will be decreased.

Comment: Hi SantaXYZ, you can look at django-rest-framework which does good data serialization and provide good rest api for you. However, to load million rows of data with each request feels like a big nono. Even if you do optimize the query process, it still takes time to return the data. I will suggest that you considering lazy loading of your data as an option

Comment: if i use lazy loading and sending 100 rows in every response to client is can i stream json responses or i should use JsonResponse for better performance in client side? because performance is the only matter here.